# Como conectar com um banco de dados já existente em Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de saber se há como me conectar ao PostgreSQL, de forma que eu só leia os dados das tabelas que já estão criadas.

Estou desenvolvendo uma API, que irá fazer a leitura num determinado banco de dados, e retornar um XML, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, o Rails foi feito para suportar bases de dados legadas também, só que você vai ter que fazer configurações adicionais.

Primeiro, configure o arquivo `config/database.yml` com as configurações do seu banco.

Ao gerar models e scaffold, use a opção `--no-migration` para evitar a criação das tabelas (que já existem):

```
rails g model post title text:text --no-migration
rails g scaffold post title text:text --no-migration
```

Depois configure manualmente o nome da tabela e chave primária:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "PRODUCT"
  self.primary_key = "product_id"
end
```

Se for usar TDD, configure também o arquivo de fixtures no TestCase do model:

```
class FunnyJoke < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  set_fixture_class funny_jokes: Joke
  fixtures :funny_jokes
  ...
end
```

Lembre-se, o guia do Rails é seu amigo: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Fonte: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Foi de grande utilidade!